# cursor.fetchall() vs list(cursor) in Python

Tags: python, mysql-python, database-cursor

Both methods return a list of the returned items of the query, did I miss something here, or they have identical usages indeed?

Any differences performance-wise?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you are using the default cursor, a `MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor`, *the entire result set will be stored on the client side* (i.e. in a Python list) by the time the `cursor.execute()` is completed.

Therefore, even if you use

```
for row in cursor:
```

you will not be getting any reduction in memory footprint. The entire result set has already been stored in a list (See `self._rows` in  MySQLdb/cursors.py).

However, if you use an SSCursor or SSDictCursor:

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors as cursors

conn = MySQLdb.connect(..., cursorclass=cursors.SSCursor)
```

then *the result set is stored in the server*, mysqld. Now you can write

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM HUGETABLE')
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

and the rows will be fetched one-by-one from the server, thus not requiring Python to build a huge list of tuples first, and thus saving on memory.

Otherwise, as others have already stated, `cursor.fetchall()` and `list(cursor)` are essentially the same.

Answer (score 14):

`cursor.fetchall()` and `list(cursor)` are essentially the same. The different option is to not retrieve a list, and instead just loop over the bare cursor object:

```
for result in cursor:
```

This can be more efficient if the result set is large, as it doesn't have to fetch the entire result set and keep it all in memory; it can just incrementally get each item (or batch them in smaller batches).

Comment: This is all true of most [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249) implementations but not MySQLdb or PyMySQL, where `list(cursor)` should arguably be preferred over `cursor.fetchall()` (because the latter inconsistently returns either a list or a tuple, whereas the former consistently returns a list) and most cursor implementations *do* fetch the entire result set into memory as soon as you start iterating over them.

Answer (score 6):

`list(cursor)` works because a cursor is an iterable; you can also use `cursor` in a loop:

```
for row in cursor:
    # ...
```

A good database adapter implementation will fetch rows in batches from the server, saving on the memory footprint required as it will not need to hold the *full* result set in memory. `cursor.fetchall()` *has* to return the full list instead.

There is little point in using `list(cursor)` over `cursor.fetchall()`; the end effect is then indeed the same, but you wasted an opportunity to stream results instead.

Comment: *"There is little point in using list(cursor) over cursor.fetchall(); the end effect is then indeed the same, but you wasted an opportunity to stream results instead."* - true for most implementations of the Python database API. Far less true in the specific case of MySQLdb or its successor, PyMySQL, where `cursor.fetchall()` has an inconsistent return type (meaning that always using `list(cursor)` reduces your potential to screw up and cause a TypeError) and most cursor subclasses do no streaming when looped over, instead reading all results into memory before yielding the first result.

Comment: @MarkAmery: which is why I carefully used the words "a good database adapter implementation". I suspected that the existing MySQL implementations were pre-fetching all results when I wrote the post.

Answer (score 5):

A (MySQLdb/PyMySQL-specific) difference worth noting when using a `DictCursor` is that `list(cursor)` will always give you a list, while `cursor.fetchall()` gives you a list *unless* the result set is empty, in which case it gives you an empty tuple. This was the case in MySQLdb and remains the case in the newer [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL), where it [will not be fixed](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/521) for backwards-compatibility reasons. While this [isn't a violation of Python Database API Specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchall), it's still surprising and can easily lead to a type error caused by wrongly assuming that the result is a *list*, rather than just a *sequence*.

Given the above, I suggest always favouring `list(cursor)` over `cursor.fetchall()`, to avoid ever getting caught out by a mysterious type error in the edge case where your result set is empty.

Answer (score -1):

You could use list comprehensions to bring the item in your tuple into a list:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = "SELECT column_name FROM db.table_name;"
cursor.execute(sql)

results = cursor.fetchall()
# bring the first item of the tuple in your results here
item_0_in_result = [_[0] for _ in results]
```

Comment: This wasn't the question.  And `_` as name is convention for names that are *not used*.  Here you are using it to access an element which is confusing.