# parse pypyodbc data from db

Tags: python, parsing, pypyodbc

I'm using the pypyodbc connector to dump data from a sql server database like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467085/pickle-and-pypyodbc-cursor)  but I need ideally to parse the data like this:

```
{ 'foo': 'bar',
'foo2': 2,
'foo3': '2018/03/09 22:12:54'),
'foo4': '15',}
```

But instead I'm getting the result as unicode and datetime:

And I hava no clue how to do so. I tried looping through query and creating a temporary list, but unsucessful.

```
def write_log(cursor, log_type):
if not os.path.exists('OfficeScan_logs'):
    os.makedirs('OfficeScan_logs')

while True:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if not row:
        print('[+] Done')
        break
    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    with open("OfficeScan_logs\\" + log_type + ".log", "r") as logs:
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
            tmp = []
            for f in row:
                if isinstance(f, unicode):
                    tmp.append(f.encode('utf-8'))
                elif id(f) and type(f) in (datetime, datetime.time):
                    tmp.append('{:%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S}'.format{f})
                else:
                    tmp.append(f)

            logs.write(pp.pformat(dict(zip(columns, tmp))) + '\n')
```

Writes:

```
{   'app_name': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
'credit': 1,
'gen_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 9, 22, 12, 54),
'groupcode': '15',}
```

EDIT: Unicode is now decoding to utf-8, but the date is still being written in datetime.datetime() format.

Comment: First, you need to fix your indentation.  Second, if I understand your code correctly, you are dropping the first row of the results. Finally, you need to show what actually gets written to the file - I don't think that the elements of `query` are what you think they are (I think they are all dicts).

Comment: Edited with the response, datetime is still being written as a function.

Comment: The bug is in `elif id(f) and type(f) in (datetime, datetime.time):`. The `id(f) and ` does nothing and `type(f) in (datetime, datetime.time)` should be `isinstance(f, datetime.datetime`.

Comment: @user2722968 this returns an error: `datetime.datetime object has no attribute 'datetime''`

Comment: You have written `datetime.datetime.datetime` somewhere. It's `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: rechecked and error persists, `isinstance(f, datetime.datetime)` and   `isinstance(f, datetime)` returns `datetime.datetime object has no attribute 'datetime''`and `isinstance(f, datetime) arg 2 must be a tuple, class or tuple of classes and types`. tried importing as `import datetime` and `from datetime import datetime`, same error.

Comment: Did you try all combinations?  If you use `import datetime`, then `isinstance(f, datetime.datetime)` should work. If you use `from datetime import datetime)` then `isinstance(f, datetime)` should work.  If neither works, check to be sure you haven't assigned something else to the name `datetime`.

Comment: Fixed guys, @cco I was using a variable called `datetime`, after renaming it problem solved. Thanks guys :)