# Python formatting CSV with string and float and write

Tags: python, csv

How do you format a float to 2 decimal points with mixed data type?
I'm fetching a table and writing rows to csv file. 
My data is (string, string, float, float, float...)

```
    sql = 'select * from testTable'
    c.execute(sql)

    columnNames = list(map(lambda x: x[0], c.description))
    result = c.fetchall()

    with open(outputCSVPath, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(columnNames)
        writer.writerows(result)
```

With the above code, I get floats with 6 decimal places. I need to format it to 2 decimal places but because of the first 2 of the list being string, it gives me an type error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the result in order to parse only the floats values, and then you can use `writer.writerows(row)` to write row by row. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861152/cursor-fetchall-vs-listcursor-in-python) to know the different ways to iterate your `results`.

On the other hand, you can format floats to two decimals points using the [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) function from python.

An example:

```
>>> # Each of your rows should be something like: 
>>> list = ["string1", "string3", 1.435654, 4.43256]

>>> #Round the floats
>>> parsed_list = [round(x, 2) if i > 1 else x for i, x in enumerate(list)]

>>> print parsed_list
['string1', 'string2', 1.44, 4.43]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the 'result' list using list comprehension and ternary if-else in Python.

`result = [x if type(x) is str else format(x,'.2f') for x in result]`