# Python Loop In HTML

Tags: python, html, for-loop

I have the following row within a table:

```
<TR>
    <TD style="text-align:center;width:50px">{% for z in recentResultHistory %} {{ z.0 }} {% endfor %}</TD>
    <TD style="text-align:center;width:100px"></TD>
    <TD style="text-align:center;width:50px">V</TD>
    <TD style="text-align:center;width:100px"></TD>
    <TD style="text-align:center;width:50px">{% for z in recentResultHistory %} {{ z.0 }} {% endfor %}</TD>
</TR>
```

when the first instance of the `{% for z in recentResultHistory %} {{ z.0 }} {% endfor %}` runs I get the expected result. When it runs for the second time it produces no results like it is not looping at all.  Do I need to reset the loop in some way?

The variable is created in my django view.py as follows:

```
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        cursor.execute("""
                        select
                        team,
                        group_concat( concat(result, '-', convert(opponent USING utf8), '-', team_score, '-', opponent_score, '-', mstatus)
                                     order by fixturedate desc
                                    separator '|') as output from plain_result
                        where (select count(*)
                               from plain_result as p
                               where plain_result.team = p.team
                               and p.fixturedate>=plain_result.fixturedate) <= 5
                        group by team
                       """)

        recentResultHistory = cursor.fetchall
```

Comment: Is `recentResultHistory` a generator?

Comment: We can't possibly answer this without seeing the source of recentResultHistory. And is this Django, or Jinja, or what?

Comment: My apologies, question updated to include the source.  It is django based.

Comment: You should call `fetchall` and then `recentResultHistory` should be a list and you have no problems.

Comment: Sorry Daniel, i am using "recentResultHistory = cursor.fetchall".  Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should be using list(cursor) rather than cursor.fetchall().  Daniel and dkasak gave me the inspiration to look and I found the following which solved my issue:

[cursor.fetchall() vs list(cursor) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861152/cursor-fetchall-vs-listcursor-in-python)