# fetch data from mysql database using Python' odo library

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, odo

I need to fetch data from a MySQL database into Pandas dataframe using [odo](http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/) library in Python. Odo's documentation only provides information on passing a table name to fetch the data but how do I pass a SQL query string that fetches the required data from the database.

The following code works:

import odo

import pandas as pd

data = odo('mysql+pymysql://username:{0}@localhost/dbname::{1}'.format('password', 'table_name'), pd.DataFrame)

But how do I pass a SQL string instead of a table name. Because I need to join multiple other tables to pull the required data.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a string directly to odo is not supported by the module. There are three methods to move the data using the tools listed.

First, create a sql query as a string and read using:

```
data = pandas.read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col=None,
                             coerce_float=True, params=None,
                             parse_dates=None, chunksize=None)[source]
```

ref http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query

Second, utilizing the odo method requires running a query into a dictionary then use the dictionary in the odo(source, destination) structure.

```
cursor.execute(sql)
results = db.engine.execute(sql)

data = odo(results, pd.DataFrame)
```

ref pg 30 of https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/odo/latest/odo.pdf

ref [How to execute raw SQL in SQLAlchemy-flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972020/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-sqlalchemy-flask-app)

ref [cursor.fetchall() vs list(cursor) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861152/cursor-fetchall-vs-listcursor-in-python)

Last, to increase the speed of execution, consider appending the pandas data frame for each result in results.

```
result = db.engine.execute(sql).fetchone()

data = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=list('AB'))
data = df_.fillna(0) # with 0s rather than NaNs

while result is not None:
    dataappend = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=list('AB'))
    data.append(dataappend)
    result = db.engine.execute(sql).fetchone()
```

ref https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

ref [Creating an empty Pandas DataFrame, then filling it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784192/creating-an-empty-pandas-dataframe-then-filling-it)

Comment: Thanks but reading database data using pandas is slow compared to ODO. Is there any way I can pass a SQL string to the ODO method?

Comment: ODO method does not query as the documentation points out. In order to utilize the (source, destination) structure you'll need to pass a dictionary as described in my edited answer.