SQL using Python - fetch speed issue
I'm attempting to run a SQL query to select two columns from a table. The issue comes when I use the cursor.fetchall() method, which takes 0.2 seconds to return the columns when in other similar cases it takes <0.01 seconds. The returned list is only 1-5 tuples long, so isn't an extreme amount of data.
cursor.execute(f"SELECT Subject, Code FROM blockPeriodsTable WHERE dataIndex={num} AND Block='A'")
blockPeriodsTemp = cursor.fetchall()

Is there a way to speed this up or is it not possible?

You may find some of the answers in this question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17861221/4018331

Are you sure it is fetchall(), and not execute(), which takes the extra time?

Aside: Don't use string formatting to substitute variables. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Different queries will take different amounts of time to execute. We'd need to see these similar cases which are faster to advise. We'd also need to see your table definition, including indexes, and a rough idea of how many rows there are. Finally, the output of explain SELECT Subject, Code FROM blockPeriodsTable WHERE dataIndex={num} AND Block='A' will give a lot of information about the performance of the query.

typically, the first time tables are accessed queries can take longer as the backend needs to do a bunch of stuff to prepare for retrieval , once done, subsequent access is usually much quicker (but thats' also dependant upon other activities happening within the db (and elapsed time, table activities))
